# return stops a function and returns a value. But why use it over a variable?

Tags: javascript, return

`return` stops a function and returns a value.  For example this simple function returns 2 words.

```
function returnValue(name) {
    return "Hello " + name;
}

document.getElementById("box-1").innerHTML = returnValue("Freddy");
```

However I can accomplish the same thing with a variable.  For example this function creates the same output without `return`.

```
var testVar;

function returnValue(name) {
    testVar = "Hello " + name;
}

returnValue("Freddy");  
document.getElementById("box-1").innerHTML = testVar;
```

As a noob, at least on the surface I don't see a significant benefit to `return` compared to a variable.  Am I missing something that is uniquely good about `return`?  Or alternately do most people simply use variables?

Comment: The second function of yours is not return anything.
It just assign the value to the global variable.

Comment: Most of the code I saw is using your first solution (Use return)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return statements tell the processor to *return* to the code that called the function. It also has the capability to report values. Using a reporter variable does not cause the function to cease.

Look below:

```
function returnValue(name) {
    if (name == "Tim") return "Bye " + name;
    return "Hello " + name;
}
```

This function stops execution if the name is Tim. With reporter variables"

```
function returnValue(name) {
        if (name == "Tim") testVar = "Bye " + name;
        testVar = "Hello " + name;
}
```

Even if the name is Tim, execution continues and the value is incorrectly reported as Tim. The variable also takes up unneccesary memory.

Comment: Very interesting!  So in a nutshell the power of `return` rests in its ability to terminate a function.

Comment: Precisely. In C/C++, the return type can also be controlled

Answer (score 1):

The return statement can be used to accomplish many different things, here are a few examples...

**Example 1:** 
In this example we have a very large loop with a condition, if we don't use the return statement in our condition it will continue to loop through every other number ultimately slowing down our code.

```
function aLargeLoop() {
  for (i = 0; i < 600; i++) {
    alert(i)
    if (i == 10) {
      return i;
    }
  }
}

aLargeLoop()
```

**Example 2:**

Instead of doing this which wastes an unnecessary amount of time to type...

```
var testVar;

function returnValue(name) {
  testVar = "Hello " + name;
}
returnValue("Freddy")
alert(testVar)
```

We can accomplish the same thing by just doing...

```
function sayhello(name) {
  return "Hello " + name;
}

var greeting = sayhello("John")
alert(greeting)
```

**Example 3:**

If we try to prototype a method like so...

```
var x;
Array.prototype.methodExample = function() {
    x = this;
  }
  [1, 2, 3, 4].methodExample()
alert(x)
```

it isn't going to work, we need to return it like so...

```
Array.prototype.methodExample = function() {
    return this;
}

alert([1,2,3,4].methodExample())
```

I hope this helps anyone else with a similar query.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable is a global variable so it can be accessed or set from anywhere in your code. In a web browser there are many global variables which are objects with functions. These are good mainly for storing data.

A function on the other hand can be used to execute a block of code or return an object.

For example, you can define a function to extract text from a string. This function will parse the R(red)G(green)B(blue) parts from a string representing a color in either Hexadecimal, RGB or RGBA format.

```
function getRGB(color) {
                var Rhex, Ghex, Bhex;
                var R8bit = null;
                var G8bit = null;
                var B8bit = null;
                var IsHex = false;
                if (color.match(/rgba?\((\d{1,3}),\s(\d{1,3}),\s(\d{1,3})/)) {
                    Rhex = RegExp.$1;
                    Ghex = RegExp.$2;
                    Bhex = RegExp.$3;
                }
                else if (color.match(/^\s*#?([0-9a-f]{2})([0-9a-f]{2})([0-9a-f]{2})\s*$/i)) {
                    Rhex = RegExp.$1;
                    Ghex = RegExp.$2;
                    Bhex = RegExp.$3;
                    IsHex = true;
                }
                else if (color.match(/^\s*#?([0-9a-f])([0-9a-f])([0-9a-f])\s*$/i)) {
                    Rhex = RegExp.$1 + RegExp.$1;
                    Ghex = RegExp.$2 + RegExp.$2;
                    Bhex = RegExp.$3 + RegExp.$3;
                    IsHex = true;
                }
                else {
                    return (NaN);
                }
                if (IsHex) {
                    R8bit = parseInt(Rhex, 16);
                    G8bit = parseInt(Ghex, 16);
                    B8bit = parseInt(Bhex, 16);
                } else {
                    R8bit = parseInt(Rhex);
                    G8bit = parseInt(Ghex);
                    B8bit = parseInt(Bhex);
                }
                return [R8bit, G8bit, B8bit];
            }
```

Now I can use that function from another function, for example to darken or lighten the color by increasing or decreasing the RGB components of the color:

```
function darken(color)  {
    var rgb = getRGB(Color);
    return [Math.Max(rgb[0]-1,0), Math.Max(rgb[1]-1,0), Math.Max(rgb[2]-1,0)];
}
```

Or to lighten a color:

```
function lighten(color)  {
    var rgb = getRGB(Color);
    return [Math.Min(rgb[0]+1,255), Math.Min(rgb[1]+1,255), Math.Min(rgb[2]+255,0)];
}
```

I can also declare variables and functions inside of a function:

```
function myColorHelper(e)
{
    var el = $(e);
    var myColor= function() { return el.css("color"); };
    var myrgb = function() { return getRGB(mycolor);};
    var makeDarker = function() {
       var darker = darken(myrgb());
       el.css("color", "rgb(" + darker[0] + ", " + darker[1] + ", " + darker[2]);
      };
    var makeLighter = function() {
       var lighter = lighten(myrgb());
       el.css("color", "rgb(" + lighten[0] + ", " + lighten[1] + ", " + lighten[2]);
      };

}
```

Plugins and frameworks are full of functions which allow us to use functionality in our code. For example, I could use jQuery with these functions to darken or lighten the color of an element on a webpage.

```
var helper = myColorHelper($('#myElement'));
helper.makeLighter();
helper.makeDarker();
```